# Not all Gradle projects are created equal, according to Netbeans

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans

I'm checking whether we'd be able to migrate from Ant to Gradle, but got confused right at the very beginning of these checks - Apache Netbeans 12 LTS (+ Gradle plugin from official repo) refuses to properly open Gradle projects that were created by a another Netbeans instance, which is a major pain.

I tried to open (in Netbeans) one of the Java library project [examples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_libraries.html) from Gradle docs, only to find out the IDE immediately spews out errors (missing imports for tests) that are unjustified and offers a very limited amount of IDE integration - forget running specific tests, even debugging is all grayed out. Gradle and Netbeans also see different classpaths.

If I create a Gradle project inside Netbeans, everything works fine - no errors, Projects Tree shows an additional tree node, called "Configurations", like in the image below, I'm able to debug and everything just works.

[image: Project Created by Netbeans]

However, even if I just copy/paste this project's directory to a different location, everything breaks after the project is reopened (I also get [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5522?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel), same thing happens for example projects found in Gradle docs).

[image: Copy of the Project]

What is going on here? Netbeans seems to know more about a project it created, than about projects that were created outside it or were just relocated. How do I force it to treat all Gradle projects equally (so that they work as expected)?

I used Gradle 7.0.1 and let the New Projects wizard "Initialize the Gradle wrapper" for the project created inside Netbeans 12 LTS. The setting to prefer existing wrappers is enabled in settings if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling an "experimental" option in Gradle options, called `Enable 'lazy' Source Group Initialization` does help with simple projects that were created by Netbeans, so they open as expected.

[image: The option]

But this does not work for Gradle projects that contain subprojects, such as the example project from Gradle docs:

[image: still broken]

The issue tracker for this Netbeans plugin has been quite active recently, mentioning issues like this, so perhaps there is hope.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is that the LTS release of Netbeans (at the time of this writing) doesn't support gradle 7. The latest release, Netbeans 12.4, is the first version that supports gradle 7.